# Clarifications need for confusing passage about kernel in Cohn's $\textit{Further Algebra with Applications}$ text

Tags: abelian-categories, morphism

The following is taken from pg 37 of: *Further Algebra with Applications* by: P Cohn.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

Let $A$ be an additive category; given a map $\alpha:X\to Y,$ we shall define the kernel of $\alpha$ as a certain subobject of $X.$   Consider all maps $\lambda:
A\to X$ such that $\lambda\alpha=0;$ for fixed $\alpha$ awe obtain a category by taking these maps as $\lambda$ as objects and as morphisms from $\lambda$ to $\lambda'$ maps $\varphi$ from the source of $\lambda$ to that of $\lambda'$ such that $\lambda=\varphi\lambda',$ with the obvious composition rule (obtained by composing maps in $A$).  A final object in this category, if one exists, is called a *kernel* of $\alpha$.  Thus a kernel of $\alpha$ is a map $\lambda:A\to X$ such that $\lambda\alpha=0$ and any other map $\lambda':A'\to X$ satisfying $\lambda'\alpha=0$ can be factored uniquely by $\lambda$, i.e. we have $\lambda'=\varphi\lambda$ for a unique map $\varphi$./ This can be expressed more briefly by saying that the kernel is the largest subobject 'killed' (i.e. mapped to $0$) by $\alpha$. The kernel need not exist, but if it does, it is unique up to equivalence, and in fact is a subobject of $X$.

> $\lambda=\varphi\lambda' \quad\lambda'=\varphi\lambda\quad (1)$

> For let $(A,\lambda)$ be the kernel and assume that $f\lambda=0;$ then by the uniqueness of the factorization, $f=0$. The kernel $A$ of $\alpha$ or also the map $\lambda$ to $X,$ will be denoted by $\text{ker }\alpha.\quad (2)$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

The two indented block above are points of confusion for me when reading the quoted passage above.  In $(1)$, is $\varphi$ suppose to be an invertible map?  Since $\lambda=\varphi\lambda',\Longrightarrow\varphi\lambda=\varphi(\varphi\lambda')\Longrightarrow\lambda'=\varphi\lambda.$ and $\lambda'=\varphi\lambda,\Longrightarrow\varphi\lambda'=\varphi(\varphi\lambda)\Longrightarrow\lambda=\varphi\lambda'.$

For $(2)$ we have earlier, the map $\lambda:A\to X,$ but what does it mean to say that "..also the map $\lambda$ to $X,$ will be denoted..."?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of "equivalence" for objects of a category?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin according to wikipedia, equivalence of categories 'is a relation between two categories that establishes that these categories are "essentially the same"'.  But I am asking about a single map $f:A\to B.$  The book on modules by T.S Blyth I am learning from, saying that an inclusion map $i:\text{ker }f\to A$ is consider as a kernel of $f$.  These type of chracterize notions are showing up, even though Blyth only mentions category theory in passing.

Comment: I didn't ask you what Wikipedia says, or what Blyth said. You are quoting a book by Cohn, which includes the phrase "it is unique up to equivalence". I am asking you what that means in Cohn's book.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin another thing is, a lot of the techniques I am learning about doing problems involving diagram chasing for exact sequences in the context of modules, the same type of exercises comes up in context of abelian categories.  But the questions I am asking, and the books I am looking over for explanations, they don't go over the motivations behind it, or why the way they are using slightly different notions about the same thing as far as talking about the properties of a map is concerned, what is it for?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin here is Cohn's definition:  "For example, an equivalence between categories is an exact functor.  We recall from BA, (Cohn's "Basica Algebra") Section 3.3 that two categories $A,B$ are $\textit{equivalent}$ if there are two functors $T:A\to B,S:B\to A$ such that $TS$ is naturally isomorphic to the identity functor on $A$ and similarly $ST$ is naturally isomorphic to the identity on $B.$

Comment: Still slipping into using MathJax to write italics, I see... That's not relevant to the statement that "the kernel [...] is unique up to equivalence", since the kernel is an object, not a category. If we don't know what the terms mean, then of course there are doubts about what the statement means. The nature of equation (1) is obviously related to the meaning of "unique up to equivalence", which is apparently an unknowable mystery.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so what does it to say kernel is an object of the map $f$?  I mean, there is an already a definition for the notion of the kernel of a map.  Why have another one.  The F-15, F-16 are newer fighter jets compare to the F-4, the later two are both fighter jets. Both can do more and do them better.  The F-117A nighthawk is a better aerial bomber, and it does the same thing as an aerial bomber, but it has stealth capabilities, which can do its job better.  Same thing apply to a regular sports car versus a F-1 racer.

Comment: Everything you write after the first sentence seems utterly irrelevant. And your first sentence shows a lack of attention: the kernel is defined to be the terminal object of a category, and not "an object of the map $f$". So... given that you seem to want to rant and not actually pay attention or provide the relevant definitions, there is nothing else for us to talk about. Please don't ping me again for this question.