# Clarifications need for unclear notations in passage from Cohn's $\textit{Further Algebra with Applications}$ text

Tags: notation, abelian-categories, morphism

The following is taken from pg 37-38 of: *Further Algebra with Applications* by: P Cohn.  It is also a continuation of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797951/clarifications-need-for-confusing-passage-about-kernel-in-cohns-textitfurthe)

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

Dually the *cokernel* of $\alpha:X\to Y$ is an initial object in the category of all maps $\mu:Y\to C$ such that $\alpha\mu=0$.  This is a quotient object of $Y$, unique up to equivalence if it exists; it (or also the map from $Y$) will be denoted by $\text{coker }\alpha$.
Given any map $\alpha:X\to Y,$ assume that $\text{ker }\alpha$, $\text{coker }\alpha$ exist.  Then we can define two further objects, the image of $\alpha$, a subobject of $Y,$ and the $\textit{coimage}$ of $\alpha$, a quotient object of $X$:

> $$\text{im }\alpha =\text{ker } \text{coker }\alpha, \text{coim }\alpha =\text{coker } \text{ker }\alpha\quad (1)$$

Again they need not exist, but if they do, they are unique up to equivalence.  Further we have the following diagram:

[image]

> Here $\text{coim }\alpha$ is the largest quotient of $X$ kiling $\text{ker }\alpha$, hence there is a map $\kappa:\text{coim }\alpha\to Y$ such that $\alpha=(\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa$. It follows that ($\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa(\text{coker }\alpha)=0;$ but $\text{coim }$ is epic, so $\kappa(\text{coker }\alpha)=0,\quad (2)$

and since $\text{im }\alpha$ is the largest subobject of $Y$ killed by $\text{coker }\alpha$, there is a unique map $\alpha:\text{coim }\alpha\to \text{im }\alpha$ to make the diagram commute.  If we had or proceeded in dual fashion, starting from $\text{im }\alpha$ and going via a map $X\to \text{im }\alpha$, we would have obtained another map $\alpha':\text{coim }\alpha\to \text{im }\alpha$ to make the square commute,

> Now $\alpha=(\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha'(\text{im }\alpha)=(\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha''(\text{im }\alpha);\quad (3)$

since $\text{coim }\alpha$ is epic and $\text{im }\alpha$ is monic, it follows that $\alpha'=\alpha''$, so the maps coincide and there is complete symmetry.  In important cases $\alpha'$ is an isomorphism.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I am having trouble deciphering notations from the above passage. For $(1)$ I understand that  if we have a map $f:X\to Y,$ the the kernel of the map $f$ can be denoted using the inclusion map $i:\text{ker }f\to A,$ and the cokernel of the map $f$ can be denoted by $w:Y\to \text{coker }f,$ where $\text{coker }f=Y/\text{im }f.$

But then why is $\text{im }\alpha =\text{ker } \text{coker }\alpha$ and $\text{coim }\alpha =\text{coker } \text{ker }\alpha$?  I look online for some explanations about this, apparently from beginning of section two of [Jeffrey Carlson's notes](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ejcarlson/coexactness(2021).pdf), he cites Saunders Mclane's Category theory text and list the following two definitions:

> The image $\text{im }f,$ is $\text{ker } \text{coker }f:\text{Im }f\to Y$

and

> The coimage $\text{coim }f$ is $\text{coker } \text{ker }f:X\to \text{Coim }f.$

I understand that coimage of $f$ is defined as $A/\text{ker }f.$  and image of $f$ is just $f(A).$  What does or how does the notations $\text{coker } \text{ker }f, \text{ker } \text{coker }f.$

For $(2),(3)$  I have the same question about the notations: $\text{coim }\alpha,\text{coim }\alpha)\kappa(\text{coker }\alpha), \kappa(\text{coker }\alpha), (\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha'(\text{im }\alpha),$ and $(\text{coim }\alpha)\alpha''(\text{im }\alpha).$  Are all these compositions between maps?  I understand that $\kappa,\alpha, \alpha''$ are maps. But for $\text{coim }\alpha, \text{coker }\alpha,$ etc.  Are they each direct images or sets or something else?